# Printing a value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iterator

Any one can help me my question is I want to print a iterating value using forloop only once.
Note:
I want to print a value like whenever iterating value is printing then before iterating value is vanish on output screen and I want to print next iterating value in the place of before iterating value is vanish to print only one value in each iteration.
Like:-
I am thinking like this is it correct or not.

```
import os
for e in range(5):
    print(e)
    os.system('cls')
```

I want to print like this:

firstly it will print 0 and the next iterating value is 1 but before printing value 1 I want to clear or delete or vanish value 0 I don't want to see value 0 and I want to to print value 1 in the place of 0.And after next iterating value 2 before printing value u don't want to see value 1 on the output screen and I want to print value 2 in the place 1

I hope are you understand this:)

Comment: Would `print(e, end='\r')` be enough?

Comment: Take a look at [`curses-menu`](https://pypi.org/project/curses-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `cls` just because not all platforms (notably linux) have a `cls` command. Also, the execution isn't as clean.

I would instead suggest you try the following:

```
for e in range(1000000):
    print(e, end="\r")
```

The `end` parameter in the `print` function lets you add something after the text. The `\r` symbol is a special ASCII character which actually tells the cursor to go backwards and thus overwrite the existing content when something is printed again.

Side note, since the execution is very fast, I changed the number in the range to be much larger so you can observe the effect.

Comment: Akilan manivannan when I am running this it will shown only 5 iterating value 4. But I think would not shown 0 or 1 or 2 ...4. Brother my question is I want to print a value 0...4 in only one place.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really sure what you are trying to say. Could you maybe provide a gif or some type of example?